# 6-pin PCIe cable for 8-pin PCIe graphics card (GTX 1070 for HP Z820)?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, cable, pci-express, adapter

Forgive me, if this has been asked before: While researching I found countless similar threads, yet virtually all of them involved a weaker power supply unit (PSU) than the one I am using. So, just to make sure...

Can anybody help me understand, if it's alright (and riskless) to power my **GTX 1070 graphics card** (which has a 8-pin PCIe power connector) using a **6-pin PCIe cable** (and an adapter)? Here's what's unclear to me:

- I understand that the 8-pin connectors basically tell the card that it's possible to draw up to 150W from the PSU. So, combining this with the 75W from the PCIe port means that the graphics card will want to get up to 225W from the PSU. I know for sure that my PSU itself can handle that, as currently, there's a card plugged into the same PCIe port that is connected using two 6-pin connectors. So, provided I just substitute the old card by the new one, the PSU should be up to the task. Correct?
- How do I know, if the 6-pin cable is capable of handling 150W instead of 75W? Is there a way to see the AWG rating?
- Assuming I would want to add the new card without unplugging the old one and I still have one free 6-pin cable... How do I know, if the PSU can handle the additional 75W necessary?
- I read that the card (MSI GeForce GTX 1070 Aero ITX) has a TDP of around 150W... So, is there a problem at all?

Here's a picture of the info on the PSU:
[image]
Can anbody help me understand all that data with respect to my graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem - I have in the past done exactly that with a GTX 1070.

The 6-pin is able to deliver all the required power.
All you need is a 8-to-6 power adapter (or was it 6-to-8?).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Do you happen to know, what amount of Watts the 6-pin cable is capable of supplying? 150, like the 8-pin cable? Is there a chance it might get too hot?

Comment: Well, all I did was go to a professional and the guy said it would work, so I bought the adapter and plugged it in, and it did work, without any heating problems ever on that PC.